# Selecting and deleting textboxs with specific text string in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to select a textbox in powerpoint with a specific word and delete it. The text box appears on each slide in the presentation, and I would like to delete each text box on each slide in the presentation. The textboxes with the word I am trying to delete has the word "Page" in it.

I have tried using some other code I seen in the internet but nothing happens to the presentation when I run the code. Wondering what I am missing for the textbox to be deleted?

I have some code I tried already:

```
Sub deletor()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim L As Long
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For L = osld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If osld.Shapes(L).HasTextFrame Then
                If osld.Shapes(L).TextFrame.HasText Then
                    ' obviously use their address
                    If LCase(osld.Shapes(L).TextFrame.TextRange) Like LCase("Page") Then
                        osld.Shapes(L).Delete
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

No error messages, just no actions in excel (the textboxes with the word page are still there). This makes me assume the macro is running but is not doing what I am trying to code it to do.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and rerun. Any error messages?

Comment: No errors come up when reomoving `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line

```
If LCase(osld.Shapes(L).TextFrame.TextRange) Like LCase("Page") Then
```

The `Like` operator uses a wildcard pattern. I would guess that the pattern you want is

```
... Like "page*"
```

or

```
... Like "*page*"
```

No need to `LCase` a string you are writing as a literal value.

Comment: I incorporated the edits and unfortunately the same result: no action was completed on the presentation. I am wondering if the error is around the for loop?

Comment: I tried it myself and it worked. Try it in a new presentation and add the text boxes manually. That should work. Work backwards from there.

Comment: I have tried in in a new presentation with manually added text boxes with alas no avail. I narrowed down that the error is in the if statement that tries to identify similar strings `If LCase(osld.Shapes(L).TextFrame.TextRange) Like "*Page*" Then` (the macro runs and deletes all text boxes if I comment this if statement out). I know we covered editing the existing code before, but is there any other way to identify & compare the string in a text box with a arbitrary string in the code using if statements?

Comment: Have a look at the InStr function.